# Wordpress site showing up with IP address rather than domain name after transfer to Google cloud

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, ip-address, cloud-hosting, google-cloud

Domain name is changed to the IP address. Website URL is working fine, new posts are working fine.

Old posts images are breaking as it's changed to the IP address instead of the domain name.  I've lost rankings in Google because of this.

I need to replace the IP address with the domain name in bulk for the entire website.